# Manual install for PHP API library for Elasticsearch

Tags: php, github, elasticsearch, github-api

I downloaded this php api package from github

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/tree/2.0

but I am having a hard time installing it. I unfortunately dont have permission to use the composer/auto-loader from where I work so I have to do it manually. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the issue exactely?

Comment: Hello, the issue is that when I try to import a file called ClientBuilder.php into a php script I am writing, it says that it cant find certain classes in ClientBuilder.php, NullLogger() being one example. I manually copy pasted the folder into unix directory where I am working and since I didnt use a composer, I thought there were some dirs/files missing so I am wondering if there is a correct way of doing this manually and if I screwed up somewhere..

Comment: Just write your own autoloader or explicitly require those files.

Comment: The NullLogger it was asking for was under Src/psr/Log/NullLogger.php and in my src folder, no such folders existed, just the Elasticsearch folder. This is why I was asking if I installed it wrong. I am an intern so I am still learning. I will try writing the loader as ray suggested, see how that goes. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes look pretty well formatted PSR-4 so you should be able to just download the directory`src/Elasticsearch`, and make a simple autoloader of your own and register it (assuming you don't already have one setup to serve classes that adhere to PSR-4).

Here's some options: `http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/`

All the other directories seem to to be extraneous to running of the classes--for unit testing and benchmarking.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help man. I will look into this. i think this is what I needed.